# Are these cracks in a basement support wall normal?

Tags: walls, basement, foundation, cracks, structure

I'm looking at a 1930's-era house that has stone foundation walls. The basement seems to have been dug out and it looks a wall was built to abut the exterior wall. The wall has a plaster or stucco coating and cracks are visible along the top and side. Do you think this is something to worry about? [image: basement wall]

Comment: I lived in a 1900-1910 house with a similar basement and cracks like that.  I never saw them get worse over time, though they did bother me aesthetically.  I'm interested what others have to say.

Comment: Some of the cracking may not be structural it may be a skim coat to provide a smother looking surface.